# Repairing pixelated image using matlab Help needed

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, pixel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCNy1.png

Hi I need help repairing this image using for loops. I know I have to identify the bad pixels first and fill them in. thanks. PS I am very new to matlab

```
clear
clc
format compact

filenameIN = uigetfile('.bmp','Picture');
noisyRGBarray = imread(filenameIN);
figure(1)
imshow(noisyRGBarray)
y = noisyRGBarray;
[m,n]=size(y)
clean=[];

for i=2:m-1
   for j=2:n-1
       if y(i,j)% clean add new
            clean = [ clean, y(i,j) ]
       end
   end
end
```

Im pretty sure the for statemetn is wrong and I do not know wat to do from here. I need help writing the for loop to go through the image matrix to identify the black and white pixels.

Comment: Post whatever code you already wrote while trying to solve this by yourself. Then point out which part of it you have a problem with.

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: Answer edited, but I think you should really hit the books so to speak, and read a few tutorials on MATLAB in general and image processing with MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a median filter on your image. See [here for an example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html).

If you must use a `for` loop for learning reasons, please explain what you consider to be a "bad pixel" (black? different from neighbors in some way?), attempt to identify such a pixel based on the criteria you settle on, and adjust the value of that pixel.

In general, you should not adopt the approach of starting with an empty array and growing it one pixel at a time.  Rather, create the output image as a copy of the input (`clean=noisyRGBarray;`) or initialize with zeros (`clean=zeros(size(noisyRGBarray))`), and modify the bad pixels (`clean(i,j,:)=...`);